# Handling different user types and data access in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am working on a React application with two user types: `Buyer` and `Seller`. A `Seller` can access some (not all) data from the user through a search bar using the user's email. So for example, if a buyer wants to know what interests the buyer to buy, and he has the user's email and did a search query it can show the user's interest if and only if the user made these data available to show if looked up.

Now, I have two user types, and one of the users `Seller` is getting access to info from the other `Buyer`. How to implement that the right way? And how to make sure the search is working properly. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can really only achieve this properly through a database, what you want to do is have a user table that contains all of the users connected to your app, then, one of the fields you would have for the user is `AccountType`, there, you would declare a 0 for a buyer or a 1 for a seller. For the search bar you would use a FlatList that contains the data you want to display, since your question is so broad I can't really provide you with examples, but if you read this you should be able to make what you want:
For the database (using MySql): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/
For the FlatList and SearchBar: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-searchbar-in-react-native/  - https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist